# OKHTTP POST Data using form builder with integer parameter

Tags: okhttp

I Wanna ask a question,
I want POST data to API that have parameter with integer data type, I already convert my parameter request that have integer value to string because Form Builder just accept String value.
But the server that I want to send expect integer value.
Is there any solution that I can use ?

The Server using header : Content-Type : x-www-form-urlencoded;

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.